# How to make Eclipse "Open Type" window to show project classes first in list, third-party classes last?

Tags: eclipse

When you work with a project you more often open classes from your project and less often third party classes, so it would be good to have project classes displayed first in "Open Type" window. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: What is your target language?

Comment: It is Java, but if you have solution for another languages, would also be interesting

Comment: Even if this question is already some years old, I opened [bug 534901](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534901) for this issue at the Eclipse bug tracker…

Comment: 10 years later, and Eclipse still cannot do this. Bug report is open since 7 years, and no one cares. Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse doesn't provide any configuration for Open Type dialog. You can only filter an unwanted packages so they will not be shown (Settings->Java->Appearance->Type Filters).

It's very simple with patterns to search for a classes within a given package. Assume I want to go to the `Node` class in the `pl.toro` package. If I just type `node` it will return more than 20 classes with my class at the end of the list. But with a pattern `p.Node` the class will be first and only. `p` stands for the first letter of the package (`pl`).

More from Eclipse's help:

> Wildcards: "*" for any string and "?" for any character
>
> terminating "<" or " " (space) to prevent the automatic prefix
>   matching, e.g.
>
> "java.*Access<" to match java.util.RandomAccess but not
>   java.security.AccessControlContext
>
> Camel case:
>
> "TZ" for types containing "T" and "Z" as upper-case letters in
>   camel-case notation, e.g.
>
> java.util.TimeZone
>
> "NuPoEx" or "NuPo" for types containing "Nu", "Po", (and "Ex") as
>   parts in camel-case notation, e.g.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> terminating "<" or " " (space) to fix the number of camel-case parts,
>   e.g.
>
> "HMap<" and "HaMap<" match "HashMap" and "HatMapper", but not
>   "HashMapEntry" nor "Hashmap".
>
> **Both pattern kinds also support package prefixes, e.g. "j.util.*Map<".**

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I don't want to hide third party classes, I just want them to be displayed always after my project classes. Thanks anyway for a hint, may be useful sometimes.